# .htaccess wildcard redirect problems

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect, wildcard

so im doing SEO for a company and they have many 404 errors and for some reason the URL is duplicating itself for example "http://greenscapeenergy.co.uk/contact/www.greenscapeenergy.co.uk/privacy-policy/"
all the 404s are with the privacy policy page after.

i want to bulk redirect anything with /privacy-policy/ in the url to redirect to the real privacy policy page. ive got this code so far but am stumped and hope anyone in the community could give me a hand!

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.greenscapeenergy\.co\.uk\privacy-policy\$
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ http://www.greenscapeenergy.co.uk/$1 [R=301,L]
```

can anyone help with this? thanks

Answer (score 1):

`HTTP_HOST` only matches HOST name in the request not including `REQUEST_URI`.

Try this rule instead:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www)?\.greenscapeenergy\.co\.uk$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?privacy-policy/(.*)$ http://www.greenscapeenergy.co.uk/$1 [R=301,L,NE,NE]
```

Comment: thank although its still not seeming to work. maybe another question is why or what reasons would there be for our URLs to be duplicating like that?

Comment: Sorry I didn't get the question. What are few examples of old & new URLs?

Comment: http://greenscapeenergy.co.uk/testimonials/solar-panel-testimonials/www.greenscapeenergy.co.uk/privacy-policy/
http://greenscapeenergy.co.uk/solar-panels/solar-maintenance/www.greenscapeenergy.co.uk/privacy-policy/
http://greenscapeenergy.co.uk/about-us/areas/www.greenscapeenergy.co.uk/privacy-policy/
 http://greenscapeenergy.co.uk/smart-heating/biomass-boilers/www.greenscapeenergy.co.uk/privacy-policy/

Comment: as you can see there are 2nd URLs being added onto the end of the 1st one. and i dont know where they came from or why they are doing this

Comment: Have you tried clearing your browser cache after using my suggested rules? Also it will be better if you can show your full .htaccess in question.